# OpenGL Shading Language TRANSFORM_TEX

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

In unity3d there is a piece of code for a vertex shader :

```
v2f vert(appdata_full v) {
    v2f o;

    o.pos = mul (UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, v.vertex);   
    o.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.texcoord, _MainTex);
    o.vertexColor = v.color * _TintColor;

    return o; 
}
```

In lines below :

```
o.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.texcoord, _MainTex);
```

what is the main task of TRANSFORM_TEX function and what is it's equiavalent in CgFx !

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's just a `Unity3D` specific **macro**, there's no `Cg` equivalent.
You can find this macro definition in the file:

> Unity\Editor\Data\CGIncludes\UnityCG.inc

It's defined this way:

```
// Transforms 2D UV by scale/bias property
#define TRANSFORM_TEX(tex,name) (tex.xy * name##_ST.xy + name##_ST.zw)
```

It scales and offsets texture coordinates. 
`XY` values controls the **texture tiling** and `ZW` the **offset**.

Comment: What does the "##_ST" appended to "name" do? Can't find anything on that.

Comment: @StevensMiller https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor#Token_concatenation